# How to use Model attributes in Controller in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have created a Model and a Controller in Yii.Now I want to use My Model attributes ($title,$message) in my Controller class.How can I do this.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mentioned as public `$title;`

then you need to write

```
$modelObj=new Model();
echo $modelObj->title;
```